# How to use Launchy via VNC (just using the keyboard)?

Tags: windows, vnc, launchy, ultravnc

My remote machine runs Launchy and UltraVNC (on XP). How can I get the UltraVNC Viewer (on XP or Windows 7) to pass the keypress to activate the Launchy window? I've tried changing the key combo from Ctrl+F1 to Ctrl+Space but that makes no difference.

Has anybody got this working via UltraVNC (or any other flavour of VNC)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using UltraVNC 1.0.9.6, pressing the ScrollLock key enables me to successfully send various shortcuts successfully. These include: Windows key + a letter, Alt + F4, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the keystroke or do you just want to use Launchy? You can click the icon in the notification area to get the Launchy bar to appear. Not as quick as a keystroke obviously but at least the option exists.

Comment: Good idea - I'd overlooked showing the system tray icon again. However, it would be nice for Launchy to work via a keystroke as the mouse pointer can be quite laggy.